# Use a specific minSdkVersion only in a Debug mode

Tags: android, gradle, android-min-sdk

How can I use a specific minSdkVersion only in a debug mode?
I want to use the minSdkVersion 21 for debug mode, but minSdkVersion 15 for the release. I don't wanna use flavors for this because will give troubles.

I think the could be like this (but don't work):

```
defaultConfig {
        applicationId "blacktoad.com.flapprototipo"
        minSdkVersion 15

        debug{
            minSdkVersion 21
        }

        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 42
        versionName "1.72"

        multiDexEnabled true
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Include Stetho only in the debug build variant](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30172308/include-stetho-only-in-the-debug-build-variant)

Comment: I think that setting flavours is the only option, check: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html#dev-build

Comment: I think that no is a duplicate.  I can't find a solution with Stetho (if you know, I beg that you say to me). I only don't wanna use Dex while I'm debuging.

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Comment: no, sorry! not a enoguh solution

Answer (score 11):

There exist a better way to do it without *Product Flavors* or hooking into the build flow.
Example:

```
  buildTypes {
     debug {
       defaultConfig.minSdkVersion 19
       defaultConfig.vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
       defaultConfig.multiDexEnabled = true
     ...
```

Comment: This looks like it would change the default for all build types. It might be working for you, but it's effectively a race condition during the gradle configure stage. If you reorder the build.gradle file, it could stop working at any time. Unless I'm missing something?

Comment: Doesn't work. Like @Hamy said - it applied the new minSdkVersion to all build types.

Comment: This is wrong. It references the defaultConfig function of the android block. The ApplicationBuildType scope itself does not provide defaultConfig.

Answer (score 4):

> I don't wanna use flavors for this because will give troubles.

I don't think you can do it without `productFlavors`. I am leaving this answer here for others who have no issue using `productFlavors`.
https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html#dev-build

Basically all you need to do is declare `productFlavors` with different `minSdkVersion`:

```
productFlavors {
    dev {
        // Enable pre-dexing to produce an APK that can be tested on
        // Android 5.0+ without the time-consuming DEX build processes.
        minSdkVersion 21
    }
    prod {
        // The actual minSdkVersion for the production version.
        minSdkVersion 14
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It took me almost a day to create this script. Please take note of this for keepsake, **but only use this as a last resort**.

```
android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->

    //Making specific variant disablements for faster build
    if (variant.buildType.name.contains("debug")) {
        println "Making min version to 21 and disabling multidex"
        variant.mergedFlavor.setMultiDexEnabled false

        def versionMin = new com.android.builder.core.DefaultApiVersion(21)
        variant.mergedFlavor.setMinSdkVersion versionMin
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question, but there is a very simple solution, even without setting up separate flavors.
 Just replace the line;

```
minSdkVersion 21
```

with

```
minSdkVersion gradle.startParameter.taskNames.toString().contains("Release")?16:21
```

and viola, it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
androidComponents {
    beforeVariants(selector().withName("debug")) { variantBuilder ->
        variantBuilder.minSdk = 21
}}
```

For more information about **beforeVariants**, can check this [link](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/extend-agp#before-variants)